# If (Aν = Bν+1) then change cell color

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns with dates. Row **A** has the check ins and row **B** has the check outs. On every row I have each reservation. I want to compare if the check out of the Nth row is the same of the check in of the (N+1)th row to change their color to one of my choosing.

It basically should be a rule within the conditional formatting.

Everything I looked up wasn't exactly what I needed, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not 100% clear if you want to color the *check-in*, the *check-out*, or *both* fields. You can combine the following two rules to achieve your desired outcome:

---

*If you want the respective **check-in** date to be highlighted:*

- select range A2:A100 (or even more, depending on your data)
- Conditional Formatting -> new Rule -> Formula
- enter `=(A2=B1)*NOT(A2="")`
- click Format -> select a color of your liking

Result: The check-in date will now be highlighted, but only if it has the same value as the check-out date right above it.

---

*If you want the respective **check-out** date to be highlighted:*

- select range B1:B99 (or even more, depending on your data)
- Conditional Formatting -> new Rule -> Formula
- enter `=(A2=B1)*NOT(B1="")`
- click Format -> select a color of your liking

Result: The check-out date will now be highlighted, but only if it has the same value as the check-in date right below it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

`IF( Aν = Bν+1)` does not make sense to me but I think I understand the body of your question. Highlighting one or the other of each pair is easy (so a rule for each, with the same colour, quite practical) but my understanding is you want pairs to be highlighted and if with a single formula this is decidedly more tricky. One way, assuming a 'modernish' Excel version and (labelled) Columns A & B (as well as the Rows A & B of your example) would be to select Columns A & B and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND($A1<>"",IF(COLUMN()=2,$B1=$A2,$A1=$B1048576))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.